# Getting two values from form submit

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

So let's say I have information in an input field that pertains to a certain ID in my database.

So, for example, if I want to change the feature of a certain object that I can only access by ID in my database I need to know not only the ID of that object, but the value that the user has entered. One way I thought of doing this is by having hidden input fields, so

```
<input type="text" name="valueEntered" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="theId"/>
<input type="submit" value="update"/>
```

So this means that when I access the results in my servlet I should get an array of values
when I do

```
request.getParameter("valueEntered");
```

If I do a similar call with name="id" , then I should also get an array of ids. I could then work under the assumption that the id at index 0 is the id of the object that has feature at index 0.

However, is there another way to do this, such that there is already a mapping between id and the value entered? As in, I don't want to rely on the assumption that the id at index i refers to the product that is to have feature at index i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the id to the name of the input field for the value as in:

```
<input type="text" name="valueEntered.theId" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="theId"/>
<input type="text" name="valueEntered.secondId" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="secondId"/>
```

This way the sequence of the fields does not matter.

Comment: unfortunately, I have no control over what can be in the id(which is a string)

Answer (score 0):

Say you have this html code with each of text,hidden have same name.

```
<input type="text" name="valueEntered" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="1"/>

<input type="text" name="valueEntered" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="2"/>

<input type="text" name="valueEntered" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="3"/>

<input type="submit" value="update"/>
```

Now you can the all text field values and hidden field values as:

```
String textValues[] = getParameterValues("valueEntered");
String hiddenValues[] = getParameterValues("id");
```

Now you can get the first text field value from `textValues[0]`
And first hidden field value from `hiddenValues[0]`

and so on...